# cxf client http rest

Tags: java, rest, cxf

All,

I am a complete beginner with cxf so forgive the simple nature of this question. I can successfully perform a GET operation and get a response object back however how do i cast this  into a type of object that I can do something useful with such as display the content?

WebClient getcxf = WebClient.create("http://mydomain.com:8090/abc/xv/test/test2/test33");

Response x = getcxf.path("/test4.xml").get();

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did have to create my own implementation however it was straightforward, thank you everybody for your help

```
    ServerGateway sg = JAXRSClientFactory.create(
            "http://localhost:8090",
            ServerGateway.class);

    String rawXml = sg.getRawXML().replaceAll("\n|\r", "");



public interface ServerGateway {

@GET
@Produces("text/xml")
@Path("/MyServer/xv/test/test2/test33/test4.xml")
public String getRawXML();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x.readEntity(type)` for example if you want response content as String `x.readEntity(String.class)`

Comment: Not sure if I'm overlooking something here but my response object does not expose a readEntity method. Its got a getEntity method but the functionality seems different

Comment: Verify are using javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Comment: @user2237585 x.readEntity is added as part of JAX-WS 2.0, I guess you might be using JAX-WS 1.1 or lower